# Receive chunks of video and play them in browser

Tags: javascript, stream, video-streaming

**Base idea:** I am creating an app. In which user chooses local file(mp4) in input field(`type="file"`) and then streams the video to other user.
I am thinking to manipulate the file in javascript. And send it chunk by chunk to another user via(datachannels webRTC) then just play it on the other side chunk by chunk.

I understand that i can "assemble" the chunks using - MediaSource API

Questions: How can i split the video in chunks using javascript? I have been googling for a while i can't seem to find a library( maybe i am googling wrong keywords? ).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [blob#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) to split the video

```js
// simulate a file
blob = new Blob(['ab'])
chunk1 = blob.slice(0, 1)
chunk2 = blob.slice(1, 2)

console.log(blob.size)
console.log(chunk1.size)
console.log(chunk2.size)
```

Comment: Yes, but will it slice a videofile(including the video and audio) ?

Comment: it will slice both audio + video

Comment: That's interesting.. Question: Have you heard about canvas captureStream? What do you think about this appraoch( i understand that browser compatablility is not that great ).

Thanks!

Comment: And also, i don't think it can chunk the audio too. The captureStream. I will experiment with your approach.

Comment: Oh, so dum of me. You are using media stream and not a video file... well then audio and video might be separated (unsure). But i know for a fact that MediaRecorder api will merge audio + video together.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at this [example](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js#save-a-media-stream) i wrote before using MediaRecorder only different is that you should send it to other peers using webrtc instead of saving it

Comment: What do you mean? I am using a video file( with video and sound together). And i need to stream the file to webrtc(janus). I am currently trying your approach.

Comment: feel even more stupid now - thought captureStream had something to with user media devices ^^ forgot everything i said

Comment: Okey, now i am confused. Your approaches looks like it has something to do with what i want to achieve.  So the Blob approach is still valid?

Answer (score 1):

Another thing i might think you are interested in is File streaming...

To get a [ReadableStream](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/) from a blob you could use the hackish why of doing

```
stream = new Response(blob).body
reader = stream.getReader()
reader.read().then(chunk => spread(chunk))
```

Another cool library otherwise you can use to stream the blob Is by using [Screw-FileReader](https://github.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader)

Comment: Wait. Is this from a chunk? Or a whole Blob?

Comment: This turns the hole blob into a stream and for each `read()` you will get a unknown chunk size back

Comment: Hmm... But how can i add this stream to werbrtc? (pc.addStream(here should be a stream). Sorry if i am asking trivial questions. I am still diging into the whole streaming business.

Comment: apparently addStream is deprecated... should use addTrack instead? i don't know what kind of stuff webrtc accepts, sorry

Comment: addStream is not depricated( we are using it in our current webcam system ).

Answer (score 1):

What wouldn't be more awesome then using [WebTorrent](https://webtorrent.io/) to share the video got everything you need... uses WebRTC...